# Jenkins SSH Connection EC2 Instance

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, jenkins

In CICD Configuration, I'm Using Jenkins as CI Server, Deployment should happen on EC2 Amazon Linux..

I tried adding my SSH configs in Jenkins, I'm getting SSH connection failed..!

The problem here is My EC2 Instance **SSH authentication requires PublicKey, Keyboard-interactive..!**

I have **enabled google authenticator** for my EC2 Instance in addition to Key authentication..!

**Can someone tell me the way to configure/bypass the keyboard-interactive authentication during deployment via Jenkins**

Comment: Disable 2FA for that account.

Comment: Our client is not ready to disable the 2FA.. Because security is a concern

Comment: Then you cannot deploy until they are ready. It does not make any sense for automated service accounts to have 2FA. There is nobody to provide the second factor, as you have already discovered!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **AWS CodeDeploy** that has an agent on the instance and can install your artifacts from Jenkins without SSH.

Alternatively you can use **AWS Systems Manager**, again it’s an agent-based way to execute scripts on the EC2 instance without the need to SSH.

Or disable SSH 2FA for certain users or for connections from the Jenkins IP.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I tried using CodeDeploy, The events are in waiting state for a period of time, After reaching timeout value, They are failed.. Let me give a try with System Manager

Comment: @ManikandanRam that looks like your CodeDeploy agent is misconfigured, maybe needs a proxy set up, or the instance IAM role doesn’t have the required perms for CodeDeploy. Check the agent logs or contact the support.

Comment: I made it @MLu with few changes + your suggestions helped me, Thank you  :)

Comment: Let me update my question regarding the fix that i gave

Comment: @ManikandanRam glad to hear that it helped. In that case please accept the answer. Thx :)

Comment: Changing the ssh configs helped to fix